# How to Index Match Duplicate Data in Excel?

Tags: excel, indexing, duplicates, match

If I used =INDEX($C$7:$C$12,MATCH(B2,$B$7:$B$12,0)) it only returns the first exact value but I need all duplicate values. How can I return all duplicate values in one cell??

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I believe Excel 2013